# Azure Mobile App Sync Service Push Failing to insert or update

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services, offline-caching

I have an Azure Mobile App Service running with Table Controllers and a local SQLite store using the `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client` and `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore` Nuget packages as demonstrated by Microsoft's documentation.

From a Xamarin.Forms application I've implemented an entity using direct calls to the Azure service using the live server data and had no problems.

Trying to do the same using the offline sync capabilities the Azure SDK provides I can pull changes down from the server to the client with no problems, but trying to change or insert records on the client then pushing the changes fails.

**Client side base entity class:**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;

public class TableObject 
{
  public string Id { get; set; }

  [UpdatedAt]
  public DateTimeOffset? UpdatedAt { get; set; }

  [CreatedAt]
  public DateTimeOffset? CreatedAt { get; set; }

  [Version]
  public string Version { get; set; }

  [Deleted]
  public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

**Client Side Model:**

```
public class UserData : TableObject
{
  public string UserId { get; set; }
  // Other properties 

  public UserData () { }
  public UserData (UserData userData) : base(userData)
  {
    UserId = userData.UserId;
  }

  public async Task<User> User()
  {
    return await Database.Instance.GetItemAsync<User>(x => x.Id == UserId);
  }
}
```

**Server Model:**

```
public class UserData : EntityData
{
  [ForeignKey("User")]
  public string UserId { get; set; }
  public User User { get; set; }
  // Other properties
}
```

My reproduction steps:

1. From client perform post to an API controller inserting a new User record in the server database. **Success**
2. Perform Push from client using sync service (pushes no records). **Success**
3. Pull new user record from server to client using sync service. **Success**
4. Create UserData records setting UserId and saving it to the client local store using the sync service. **Success**
5. Push new record from local store to server using sync service. **Fails**

   catch (MobileServicePushFailedException exc)
   {
     if (exc.PushResult != null)
     {
       syncErrors = exc.PushResult.Errors;
     }
   }

**exc stack trace:**

```
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.MobileServiceSyncContext+<ExecuteSyncAction>d__34.MoveNext () [0x00090] in <24dbefba60fd49f4b193cdf58abf3290>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.MobileServiceSyncContext+<PushAsync>d__33.MoveNext () [0x00143] in <24dbefba60fd49f4b193cdf58abf3290>:0
```

PushResult has a single failed insert and the item contains 2 properties (Id, UserId). Result and Status are null, Handled is false, and the post method in the table controller is never called. Keep in mind during pull the Get method on the table controller is called.

This also happens if we pull the user record, update it locally, then try pushing it up.

Comment: Try adding a MobileServiceSyncHandler as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52288943/microsoft-azure-mobile-client-handling-server-error-using-custom-imobileservic/52323808#52323808 to get a better idea of what the underlying error is when you try doing a Push.

Comment: I have tried adding a MobileServiceSyncHandler, both the default one and a custom one. The problem doesn't appear to be the error with a database update, but rather it is that the push never even reaches the Table controllers during the process. After calling PushAsync() the black box that is this method never reaches the table controller in the server project. On startup the PullAsync() methods successfully reach the table controllers, but then pushing it doesn't.

I was wondering if this was an authentication issue but was able to call the table controllers from PostMan with no problems.

Comment: What permissions do you have set for the PATCH and POST operations on the server?

Comment: We haven’t found any more info about this, we decided to switch to ASP.NET Core 2.1 and implement the syncronization ourselves. This looked like a nice out of the box solution but it seems to have some tricks and a lack of documentation... from what I’ve been gathering Microsoft isn’t actively working on this since Adrian Hall left.