# Azure Mobile Apps: Sync retry on failure

Tags: android, azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I'm using Azure Mobile Apps for a Xamarin app which is used on big festivals. We have always connections issues caused by the mass of mobile devices hanging aroud there. The Azure Mobile Apps SDK pretty good manages the (offline-) syncing in this environment, BUT:

What is the correct way to implement a retry-mechanism, if the device fails to push it's updated data to the server? I'd like the device to aggressivly retry the sync of data (maybe only some specific types).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Containing your sync code in a try/catch will allow you to retry the call before ultimately failing. Here is an example where someone has multiple retries for certain error types: [Microsoft.Azure.Mobile Client - Handling Server Error using custom IMobileServiceSyncHandler - Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52288943/microsoft-azure-mobile-client-handling-server-error-using-custom-imobileservic)

As far as an incremental push goes, [according to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync) this is not possible.

"Push is an operation on the sync context and sends all CUD changes since the last push. Note that it is not possible to send only an individual table's changes, because otherwise operations could be sent out of order. Push executes a series of REST calls to your Azure Mobile App backend, which in turn modifies your server database."

You can choose which tables to pull if there is specific data that is critical to update, but the app will always try to push all updated data before any pulls will happen.